# Get Min and Max time in date and include null dates within a single column in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, oledb

I have a column named TimeLog

[image]

I want to get the min and max time in a day in a date range including null date values. Note this is Oledb/MS Access.

So far this is my query:

```
commstring = "
    SELECT FORMAT([LogTime],'MM/dd/yyyy')  AS LTime, MIN(LogTime) AS MinTime, MAX(LogTime) AS MaxTime 
    FROM TimeLog 
    WHERE (#" & fromdate & "# <= LogTime OR LogTime IS NULL) 
        AND (#" & todate & "# >= LogTime OR LogTime IS NULL) 
        AND UserID = '" & NumCmbBox.Text & "' 
    GROUP BY FORMAT([LogTime],'MM/dd/yyyy') 
    ORDER BY MAX(TimeLog.LogTime)
"
```

Comment: what's the error here? you can start by removing the order by

Comment: @maSTAShuFu There is no error, but the output I desired is not included. I want to also show null dates.

Answer (score 0):

Try this old trick with Nz:

```
WHERE (#" & Format(fromdate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# <= Nz(LogTime, Now())) 
    AND (#" & Format(todate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# >= Nz(LogTime, Now())) 
    AND UserID = '" & NumCmbBox.Text & "'
```

or without:

```
WHERE ((#" & Format(fromdate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# <= IIf(LogTime Is Null, Now(), LogTime)  
        AND #" & Format(todate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# >= IIf(LogTime Is Null, Now(), LogTime)) 
        OR LogTime Is Null)
    AND UserID = '" & NumCmbBox.Text & "'
```

or using *Between - And* (tested and works here):

```
WHERE ((LogTime BETWEEN #" & Format(fromdate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# AND #" & Format(todate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#) OR (LogTime Is Null))
    AND (UserID = '" & NumCmbBox.Text & "')
```

You may also try:

```
WHERE ((Nz(LogTime, Date()) BETWEEN #" & Format(fromdate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# AND #" & Format(todate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#) OR (LogTime Is Null))
    AND (UserID = '" & Me!NumCmbBox.Value & "')
```

Comment: I get an error saying `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Undefined function 'Nz' in expression.'`

Comment: The IIF doesn't include the null dates.

Comment: I think the formatting error is wrong? I tried rearranging. Can't seem to fix the parenthesis.

Comment: You may be right. I've edited it a bit - see answer.

Comment: `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException` isn't a VBA error message is it?  `NZ` is specific to Access VBA so it will return an error if called from `.Net` or some other environment won't it?

Comment: If my previous comment is correct you'd assign `LogTime` or `Now()` to a temp variable and use that within your SQL:  `varTemp = IIf(IsNull(LogTime), Now(), LogTime)`

Comment: @Gustav still doesn't display the null dates.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook fromdate and todate is from a DateTimePicker.

Comment: You may prefer the _Between - And_ syntax. See edited answer. If this not works at you, something else is going on.

Comment: @Gustav: Does my selection or group by affect the output? :commstring = "SELECT FORMAT([LogTime],'MM/dd/yyyy') AS LTime, MIN(LogTime) AS MinTime, MAX(LogTime) AS MaxTime FROM TimeLog 
                          WHERE ((LogTime BETWEEN #" & Format(fromdate, "yyyy\/MM\/dd") & "# AND #" & Format(todate, "yyyy\/MM\/dd") & "#) OR (LogTime Is Null))
                          AND (UserID = '" & NumCmbBox.Text & "') GROUP BY FORMAT([LogTime],'MM/dd/yyyy')"

Comment: No, that seems OK, but perhaps the Null values disturb. See edited answer using Nz and, also, a modification of the combobox value.